# Define a macro that returns the operator of an expression in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I'm looking for functionality like this:

```
(op (+ 1 2))
; +
```

I can’t for the life of me seem to figure out how to do this using `define-macro`. Any help?

Thanks,

Edit:

It's especially confusing cause I can do:

```
(car '(+ 1 2))
; +
```

But if I do:

```
(define-macro (op expr)
    (car expr))

(op '(+ 1 2))
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Which Scheme implementation are you using? `define-macro` is not part of the Scheme standard. It has `define-syntax`.

Comment: If this is MzScheme, I think the syntax is `(define-macro op (lambda (expr) ...))`. You can't abbreviate the `lambda` like you can when defining functions.

Comment: It isn't — damn unfortunately my school is using a custom implementation of scheme.

Comment: Try using `(define-macro (op expr) (write expr))` to see what the actual value of `expr` is.

Comment: "_But if I do... it doesn't work._" -- Doesn't work how? What _does_ happen with `(op '(+ 1 2))`?

Comment: Error: unknown identifier: quote. I think it treats the quote as part of the list and then car's that, and then tries to evaluate quote

Answer (score 2):

OP has defined the macro `op` as if it were a function, but Lisp macros do not work this way. The macro form is evaluated to produce a new form which substitutes for the original macro call, yet the macro arguments are passed into the macro body *unevaluated*. This means that within the macro body of `op`, `car` operates not on the data `(+ 1 2)`, but rather on the data `(quote (+ 1 2))`.

The goal of the macro `op` is not to evaluate `(car expr)`, but to produce the *form* `(car expr)` (where `expr` is replaced by the value of the macro argument), which is then evaluated in the REPL after the macro expansion has taken place. One could do this either using `list`:

```
(define-macro (opl expr)
  (list 'car expr))
```

or using *quasiquotation*:

```
(define-macro (opq expr)
  `(car ,expr))
```

Here, the backquote introduces a template for a list, and the comma causes the symbol `expr` to be evaluated to its value (`(quote (+ 1 2))`), and the result inserted into the list. A simple quoted list, e.g. `'(car expr)` would evaluate to the list `(car expr)`, where `expr` is just the symbol `expr`. With quasiquotation, `,expr` evaluates to the value of the argument provided in a macro call, e.g. `` `(car ,expr) `` --> `(car '(+ 1 2))`. Note that `(list 'car expr)` produces the same form when `expr` is `'(+ 1 2)`, as with `(opl '(+ 1 2))`

This `define-macro` syntax is almost identical to the traditional `defmacro` syntax of Common Lisp, the difference there being that with `defmacro` the name of the macro goes before a list of formal parameters, e.g. `(defmacro op (expr) ;...)`. `define-macro` is not available in Standard Scheme, but some Scheme implementations *do* support it. Guile Scheme supports both `defmacro` and `define-macro`. Both of the above macro solutions work in Guile:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (opl '(+ 1 2))
$2 = +
scheme@(guile-user)> (opq '(+ 1 2))
$3 = +
```